# Uploading pictures into a folder from form in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a form that contains a choose file field. I want to upload a pic into a particular folder. I am able to upload the file into database but couldn't see it in the specific folder where i am moving it into.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to read [How do I write a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

specify destination like

```
$destination  = 'destination folder';
```

and after saving your records to database, to move the image into destination folder,

```
 Input::file('image')->move($destination, $fileName)
```

where `$filename` is a name of image

Comment: Thank you for the solution but still i am getting the following error."
Call to a member function move() on null".

Comment: `Input::file('image')->move($destination, $fileName)` add this line before you call the `save`  method. I think you are moving file to destination after saving record to database.